# React getElementById TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I use this in Pure React

```
const Fleet = () => {

    const closeSm = () => {
        document.getElementById("mysideMenu").style.width = '0';
        document.getElementById("pg-content").style.marginLeft='0';
    }

    const openSM = () => {
        document.getElementById("mysideMenu").style.width = '250px';
        document.getElementById("pg-content").style.marginLeft='250px';
    }

    const sideMenu = () => (
        <>
            <div id='mysideMenu' className='sidemenu'>
                <a href='javascript:void(0)' className='close' onClick={closeSm} >&times;</a>
            <div className='sm-wrapper'>
                <a href='#'>Home</a>
                <a href='#'>Portfolio</a>
                <a href='#'>About</a>
                <a href='#'>Contact</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id='pg-content'>
                <div style={{fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer', color:'#5b5b5b'  }} onClick={openSM} >&#9776;</div>
                    <h1>Side menu</h1>
                    <span>Tutorial</span>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

It is working very well, but when I change to TypeScript like this:

```
const Fleet = () => {

    const myElement: HTMLElement | any = document.getElementById('mysideMenu');
    const myContent: HTMLElement | any = document.getElementById('pg-content');
    
    
    const closeSm = () => {
        myElement.style.width = '0';
        myContent.style.marginLeft='0';
    }

    const openSM = () => {
        myElement.style.width = '250px';
        myContent.style.marginLeft='250px';
    }

    const sideMenu = () => {
        
        
        
        return(
        <>
            <div id='mysideMenu' className='sidemenu'>
                <button style={{fontSize:'60px'}} className='close' onClick={closeSm} >&times;</button>
            <div className='sm-wrapper'>
                <img src={Ferte} alt='/'/>
                <h2 className='text-center mt-5'>Saint Georges</h2>
                <a href='#'>About</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id='pg-content'>
                <div style={{fontSize:'30px', cursor:'pointer', color:'#5b5b5b'  }} onClick={openSM} >&#9776;</div>
                    <h1>Side menu</h1>
                    <span>Tutorial</span>
            </div>
        </>)
    }
```

It is not working very well. It is to open a side bar. I don't know why I have this problem!

this are my complete Components. the first one with Pure React and the second one with Typescript.. as you see is the same.. but for any reason in typescript doesnt work, i mean , if for any reason i edit the pixels and i save in the VisualCode magically will work but if i reload the page doesn't work.. i know is a weird problem is because of this i ask here

Comment: What do you mean by "not working very well" and why are you using `any`?

Comment: yes i mean , if i change the pixels and i save is working but if i reload the page doesn't work and React crashed and throw me a error                                                              ```TypeError: myElement is null
openSM
C:/Users/troya/Desktop/inarix-portal1/src/components/Fleet.tsx:17

  14 |    }
  15 | 
  16 |    const openSM = () => {
> 17 |        myElement.style.width = '250px';
     | ^  18 |        myContent.style.marginLeft='250px';
  19 |    }
  20 | ```

Comment: No need to explicitly define  this type: `HTMLElement | any`

Comment: but is only in typescript because in jsx works very well and i dont have any problem

Comment: The main difference is that in your second example, you're calling `document.getElementById` outside the functions instead of inside them. If `Fleet` is the component that will render those components to screen, they probably don't exist yet. That's why `myElement` and `myContent` are `null` and you can't change their styles.

Comment: @rickdenhaan so, what is your advice? becase if i reload is not working but if for any reason i change the styles and i save ,works very well. so i dont know

Comment: Why are you doing anything here with `document.getElementById`? You are effectively storing implicit state in the DOM that is untracked. By doing this you risk a divergence of VDOM and actual DOM. Why not use `style` property on the actual JSX/TSX elements and have the style change according to application state? A combination of the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and the `style` property or a changing of the `className` property with appropriate CSS will be much more robust than your current, flawed approach.

Comment: @spender you are right! im doing this as a interactive exercise, only that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *rarely* want to manipulate the DOM directly for React components.

The best solution here is to use `state` to keep track of whether the sidebar is open or not, then render the correct styles depending on the open state:

```
const Fleet = () => {
    const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    const closeSm = () => {
        setIsSidebarOpen(false);
    }

    const openSM = () => {
        setIsSidebarOpen(true);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div id='mysideMenu' className='sidemenu' style={{ width: isSidebarOpen ? 250 : 0 }}>
               ...
            <div id='pg-content' style={{ marginLeft: isSidebarOpen ? 250 : 0 }}>
```

If you absolutely WANT to manipulate the DOM directly, use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead:

```
const Fleet = () => {
    const myElement = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
    const myContent = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

    const closeSm = () => {
        myElement.current.style.width = '0';
        myContent.current.style.marginLeft='0';
    }

    const openSM = () => {
        myElement.current.style.width = '250px';
        myContent.current.style.marginLeft='250px';
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div id='mysideMenu' className='sidemenu' ref={myElement}>
               ...
            <div id='pg-content' ref={myContent}>
```

Comment: Thanks! was cool the solution with Ref! the other one with useState yes i know how to do it! but how i said , i was doing some excercises to manipulate the Dom! anyway! perfect! and thanks alot!